# UI-router child resolves delays parent loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The resolves of a child state are delaying the loading of the parent state

My states are configured as:

```
$stateProvider
          .state('a', {
            url: '/a/:aid',
            controller: 'ACtrl',
            templateUrl: 'a.html'
          })
          .state('a.b', {
            url: '/b/:bid',
            controller: 'BCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'b.html',
            resolve: {
              DataService: 'DataService',
              data: function(DataService) {
                return DataService.getData(); //Returns a http promise
              }
            }
          });
```

index.html:

```
<nav>
  ....
</nav>
<div ui-view></div>
```

a.html has:

```
<sidebar>
...
</sidebar>
<div ui-view></div>
```

b.html has:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data">{{ d }} </div>
```

When I hit the url http://example.com/a/1/b/1 a.html does not immediately load.
I seems that state 'a' is waiting for the resolves of the child state 'a.b' to complete.

What I would like to do it load a.html (show the sidebar and an empty div) probablby with a loading icon while the child state resolves its dependencies.
**[edit]
Please notice that my state 'a' does not have resolves but it still waits for its child resolves. I want to mainly avoid this**

Once everything is loaded and when I change the `bid` I want it to again show a loading icon while the child resolves the new data.

This is my first time posting a question so I apologize in advance if I wasen't clear enough.

Comment: As far as I remeber one of [Chris T](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3225368/) *(UI-Router team member)* comments, this is planned in one of next releases

Comment: Thanks Radim Köhler, you gave me some hope. I will check their github page to see if I can verify this.

Comment: Hi Ralph, I am also experiencing exactly the same issue. Parent waiting for it's child resolve to complete. Were you able to confirm if they are working on a fix in Github? Also, what did you end up doing as an alternative? My main issue is entire View is blocked from rendering because of a child resolve which is a major bug in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**Loading Order**

Ui-router first loads parent then child when you are accessing child directly. Please check this from  your firebug.

In your case, The following is the order

- a.html
- a.b resolve process (XHR request)
- a.b.html

**For Displaying loading image**

***Approach 1***

You can try [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) module. it is managing the headache of show/hide loading in page while XHR request processing. This loading image will show in top of the browser.

> The idea is simple: Add a loading bar / progress bar whenever an XHR
>   request goes out in angular. Multiple requests within the same time
>   period get bundled together such that each response increments the
>   progress bar by the appropriate amount.
>
> This is mostly cool because you simply include it in your app, and it
>   works. There's no complicated setup, and no need to maintain the state
>   of the loading bar; it's all handled automatically by the interceptor.

***Apprach 2***

If you want to display the loading image in a specific place based on the screen, you need to handle it through your controller using ng-show/ng-hide

Comment: The most important this here is that my a.html dosen't load until its child promises are resolved. What this means is I want to show my sidebar (a.html contents) first and then let the child load after it resolves its dependencies.

Comment: oops! I believe, that parent state should load first then your child  state. Means a.html > a.b resolve process > a.b.html ...Can you confirm this using firebug or any other developer tool..Please post the screen shot also....Next time, please post your question clearly...